# why "java -version" shows error in super user mode but not in guest user mode

Tags: java, ubuntu

[image]

java -version     in guest user mode returns version, but in superuser mode shows class not found exception. Why?

Comment: Suggestion.  In this case an actual cut and paste of the text would be more helpful than the screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screen shot it looks as if you were using different characters ([dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) vs. [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen)). Java does not recognize the second one (from super user mode) as option indicator and tries to execute a class named "-version".

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) you can see that the command-line options (which `-version` is) are optional, so if Java fails to recognize your second `-version` as an option, it will just treat it as classname.

I cannot explain where that dash came from, but it should work if you copy&paste the working command from guest user mode.

Comment: yeah....  in the second case...  it is executing as if -version is some class name, which it is not able to find

Comment: @AshwaniKumarRahul I think Marvin might be on the right track. Can you please copy and try the "working `java -version` version" which you've tried with the *"ashwani"* user?

Comment: What's the difference between a dash and a hyphen?  I always thought they were the same thing.  On my keyboard they are.  Is this a new Gatesian atrocity?

Comment: @SteveCohen: [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). [Hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen).

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @SteveCohen: Did you read the Wikipedia articles? "A dash is a punctuation mark that is similar to a hyphen or minus sign, but differs from both of these symbols primarily in length and function."

Comment: No, but now I have.  Thanks for the information.  Yes, it's a Gatesian atrocity.  I HOPE it can be avoided simply by pressing the hyphen key (next to zero) on the top or the minus key on the numeric keypad.  On any keyboard I've ever worked with, these produce the same correct value and the one you want.

Comment: @Tom yes marvin is ryt....  actually i copied the command from a web page, where it was hyhen instead of dash... Thats why i was getting error...  Interestingly when i pasted it in guest user mode it appeared as dash, but when i pasted it in root user mode it appeared as hyphen....   Anyways...  Thanks a lot Guys...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your path is different and you are executing a different `java.exe`.  Use the command `which java` in both environments to check this.

Comment: exe is a windows extension

Comment: True but java -version is supported for every version of java I ever knew about.  Pretty pointless if that were not the case.